# How to pixelate a 2D game in Godot?

Tags: godot, pixelate

So I am making a 2D Godot game and I think it will be useful if I can pixelate the whole viewport. Maybe I need a `canvas_item` shader, but I have no idea how to do it. Can someone explain how to do it and why it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out myself by experimenting with the parameters.

*Note:* this method doesn't use any interpolation.

There is a `Window` tab in the `Project Settings`, and there are size properties in it. I needed to reduce that size by some number - the size of the pixel, like if my screen is 1920x1080, and each pixel is 10x10, then I set the size to 192x108.

Then I set the `Stretch` mode to `viewport` to pixelate.

And now it works just fine.